# Create grid in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an nXn grid in c++. So far I have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

   int num_rows;
   int num_columns;
   string board[num_rows][num_columns];

   cout << "Enter number of rows" <<"\n";
   cin >> num_rows;
   cout << "Enter number of columns" <<"\n";
   cin >> num_columns;



   for (int i=0; i<num_rows;i++){
     for(int j=0; j<num_columns; j++){
       if(j ==0)
          board[i][j]="|_|";
       else
          board[i][j]= "_|";
     }
  }


    for (int i=0; i<num_rows;i++){
     for(int j=0; j<num_columns; j++){
       cout<< board[i][j];
     }
       cout<<"\n";
  }



    return 0;
}
```

The code works up to 3X3. for 5X5 I get output like:

|*|*|*|?;????G??*|P?G?? ?;??p_|
|*|*|*|?;????G??*|P?G?? ?;??p_|
|*|*|*|?;????G??*|P?G?? ?;??p_|
|*|*|*|?;????G??*|P?G?? ?;??p_|
|*|*|*|?;????G??*|P?G?? ?;??p_|

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: `string board[num_rows][num_columns];` is not standard C++, although some compilers support it.  However, your subscript variables have not yet been initialized so you get Undefined Behavior even with those compilers that do support VLAs.

Answer (score 0):

For variable-length arrays, you can use vector, the following is the modified code

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int num_rows;
  int num_columns;
  vector<vector<string>> board;

  cout << "Enter number of rows"
       << "\n";
  cin >> num_rows;
  cout << "Enter number of columns"
       << "\n";
  cin >> num_columns;

  for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    vector<string> row;
    for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
      if (j == 0)
        row.push_back("|_|");
      else
        row.push_back("_|");
    }
    board.push_back(row);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_columns; j++) {
      cout << board[i][j].c_str();
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```